# Python array indexing

Tags: python

I am writing a code for doing some integration. But I am stuck at some point(the last two lines). As it says Index Error: Index out of bounds. What I would like to do is- each time r has a value it should write to the empty corresponding index as an increment of 1 so that it can keep track of it. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code-

```
from pylab import*
from math import*

dx = 981
dy = 1043
bx = 534.4
by = 109.5

index = zeros(shape=(1,dx+dy))
r=0
r_max=0

for i in xrange(1,dy+1):
    for j in xrange (1,dx+1):
        if i-by > 0:
            theta = 180*atan(abs(j-bx)/(i-by))/pi
            if theta<10:
                r = round(sqrt((j-bx)**2+(i-by)**2))
                if r>0:
                    index[r]+=1
```

Comment: Just a general tip: You should (usually) not use `from foo import *`. It's better to `import foo` and then call `foo.bar()`. For example, I was thrown off by `zeros()` - where is it defined? You can't tell. If you do `import pylab` and then call `pylab.zeros()`, it's much easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: TimPietzcker is absolutely right, this code would start producing weird behaviour if you would add NumPy to it as well (due to the numpy.zeros).

Comment: will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `index = zeros(shape=(1,dx+dy))` you create a 2-dimensional array, with the first axis of size 1.  When you do `index[r]+=1` you access that first axis of the array, with index `r`, which can be > 1.

So it looks like what you want is to get rid of the first "useless" dimension, by doing

```
index = zeros(shape=(dx+dy))
```

Or, alternatively, indexing the second axis:

```
index[0, r]+=1
```

Or,

```
index[:, r]+=1
```

Comment: @user2095624 glad I could help. If you find an answer helpful, feel free to accept it